# Is there any way make an array list which is mixing all of it's components between each other not repeat said components if needed

Tags: java

my code takes an array list like "abc" and combines the letters in the array list in all possible combinations, for example

"ab" returns

"aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb"

I can also modify it's length.

My problem here is that I only want to use each letter once if I only have 1 of said letter, for example if I only have 1 letter "a" I only want my program to use 1 letter "a", but if I have two letters "a", for example "aa" I do want it to use both of those As on all positions.

Here's the code:

```
public class Words {
    static char[] alphabet = "ab".toCharArray();

    static void generate(StringBuilder sb, int n) {
        if (n == sb.length()) {
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            return;
        }
        for (char letter : alphabet) {
            sb.setCharAt(n, letter);
            generate(sb, n + 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int length = 2; length <= 3; length++) {
            sb.setLength(length);
            generate(sb, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *PLEASE* come up with a better subject than "Is there any way to fix this?"  And please clarify what you're trying to do.  It sounds like a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).  Are looking for something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-permutations

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the letters already used in the current string `sb` by additionally counting the frequency of each character and, let's say saving it to a map.
The key would be the character and the value of its frequency.

Now instead of iterating all letters of the alphabet in the `generate()` method, you would iterate the maps keyset, decreasing the value of the character used subsequently and deleting it from the map once it reaches 0.

This will reduce the charset available for the next recursion steps. For input "ab" the algorithm would output "ab, ba". I hope this idea helps.